# Sorting a list of list in Scheme

Tags: list, sorting, scheme

I have a function that takes a list and outputs the powerset of that list. So given, `(1 2 3)` it should output `(() (1) (2) (3) (1 2) (1 3) (2 3) (1 2 3))`.

I am currently getting the correct values, it just not in a nice order. The current output is `(() (3) (2) (2 3) (1) (1 3) (1 2) (1 2 3))`.

I wrote two functions that will be passed to the standard sort function to check the length of each element and if it is in order and sort accordingly. The output of that gives me `((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1) (2 3) (2) (3) ())`.

What am I doing wrong in these two functions given the final-list is `(() (3) (2) (2 3) (1) (1 3) (1 2) (1 2 3))`?

;define element-ordered

```
(define (element-ordered? ls0 ls1)
    (cond
        [(equal? ls0 ls1) #t]
        [(< (car ls0) (car ls1)) #t]
        [else #f]))
```

;define length-ordered

```
(define (length-ordered? ls0 ls1)
    (cond
        [< (length ls0) (length ls1) #t]
        [> (length ls0) (length ls1) #f]
        [eq? (length ls0) (length ls1) (element-ordered? ls0 ls1)]))
```

;sort using provided sort

```
(sort final-list length-ordered?))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your `element-ordered?` function is quite correct. Here's what I came up with:

```
(define (element-ordered? ls0 ls1)
    (cond
        ((< (car ls0) (car ls1)) #t)
        ((> (car ls0) (car ls1)) #f)
        (else (element-ordered? (cdr ls0) (cdr ls1)))
    )
)

(define (length-ordered? ls0 ls1)
    (cond
        ((< (length ls0) (length ls1)) #t)
        ((> (length ls0) (length ls1)) #f)
        (else (element-ordered? ls0 ls1))
    )
)
```

Note also that in your code snippet, the conditions of `length-ordered?` are not parenthesized correctly, so this might have also caused a problem with your function.

Comment: I fixed that parentheses in length-ordered? and I receive my expected output with your slight fix. Thanks for the help!